# How to clone gitlab repo over tor using ssh?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, clone, tor

#### Error message

After having added the ssh key of a user of a GitLab server and repository that is hosted over tor, a test was performed that tried to clone a private repository (to which the testing user is added) over tor. The cloning was attempted with command:

```
torsocks git clone git@some_onion_domain.onion:root/test.git
```

Which returns error:

> Cloning into 'test'... 1620581859 ERROR torsocks[50856]: Connection
> refused to Tor SOCKS (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:543)
> ssh: connect to host some_onion_domain.onion port 22: Connection
> refused fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

#### GitLab SSH Cloning Verification

However, to verify the ssh access is available to the test user, the cloning was verified without tor using command:

```
git clone git@127.0.0.1:root/test.git
```

Which successfully returned:

> Cloning into 'test'... remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done. remote:
> Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done. remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused
> 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.

#### Server side hypothesis

- My first guess is that it is a server-side issue that has to do with the lack of `https`, in following setting in the `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` file:

```
external_url 'http://127.0.0.1'​
```

However setting `external_url 'https://127.0.0.1` requires an https certificate, e.g. from Let's encrypt, which seem to not be provided for onion domains.

#### Client-side hypothesis

- My second guess would be that it is a client-side issue related to some `SOCKS` setting is incorrect at the test user side that runs the `torsocks` command, similar to an issue w.r.t. the `SOCKS 5` protocol that seems to be described [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4855/is-it-possible-to-have-a-hidden-git-service?rq=1).

#### Question

Hence I would like to ask:

*How can I resolve the `connect to host some_onion_domain.onion port 22: Connection refused` error when users try to clone the repo over tor?*

Answer (score 1):

One can set the ssh port of the GitLab instance to 9001, e.g. with:

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname gitlab.example.com \
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:9001 \
  --name gitlab \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

Next, add port 9001 and port 22 to the ssh configuration in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by adding:

```
Port 9001
Port 22
```

then restart the ssh service with: `systemctl restart ssh`.

It is essential that one adds a public ssh key to the GitLab server **for each** computer you want to download the repo from, even if one wants to clone a public repository. You can make a new GitLab account for each computer, or add multiple public ssh keys to a single GitLab account. [These instructions](http://%20https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account) explain how to do that,  tl;dr

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
<enter>
<enter>
<enter>
systemctl restart ssh
xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

Ps. if xclip does not work, one can manually copy the ssh key with: `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`.

Then open a browser and go to https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys so for your own tor GitLab server that would be: someoniondomain.onion/-/profile/keys, and copy paste that key in there.

That is it, now one can clone the repository over tor with:

```
torify -p 22 git clone ssh://git@someoniondomain.onion:9001/root/public.git
```

### Note

As a side note, in the question I happened to have tested `git clone git@127.0.0.1:root/test.git` however, instead of using `127.0.0.1` I should have used either the output of `hostname -I` or the public ip address of the device that hosts the GitLab server. Furthermore, I should have verified whether the GitLab server was accessible through ssh by testing:

```
ssh -T git@youronionserver.onion
```

Which should return `Congratulations..`. It would not have done so if I had tested that, indicating the problem was in the ssh access to the GitLab server (or the ssh connection to the device). I could have determined whether the ssh problem was with the device or the ssh server by testing if I could log into the device with: `ssh deviceusername@device_ip`, which would have been successfull indicating, the ssh problem with at the GitLab server.